# Using SVC webservices in Objective-C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

I am trying to make my iPhone application connect to my Webservices. I don't have much experience with this Webservices so this is why I ask here for information/help.

I first tried to send XML files back and forth, well this takes too much time. Now I found out that there is an application called: wsdl2objc. It generates some objective C files but I don't have any idea how to use it.

Could someone push me in the right direction?

Below here is one of the SVC files that I open in the browser!

```
Metadata Service

You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

svcutil.exe http://server/SB2/services/Metadata.svc?wsdl

This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:


C#

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        entitiesClient client = new entitiesClient();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}


Visual Basic

Class Test
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim client As entitiesClient = New entitiesClient()
        ' Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        ' Always close the client.
        client.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

After generating de source code, it doesn't want to compile:

```
- (BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBindingResponse *)RetrieveUsing;
- (void)RetrieveAsyncUsing delegate:(id<BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBindingResponseDelegate>)responseDelegate;
- (BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBindingResponse *)DefinedEntitiesUsing;
- (void)DefinedEntitiesAsyncUsing delegate:(id<BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBindingResponseDelegate>)responseDelegate;
```

Error:

```
error: expected ';' before 'delegate'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just copy the generated files into your project. Suppose your service is called ClientService and the operation is ClientOperation, there should be a class with corresponding name (ClientService.m)v - this is your starting point.

The wsdl2objc genereates necessary bindings as well as data classes according to the wsdl. If your service does require any parameters, you should be able to set up the request instance accordingly.

```
ClientServiceSOAPBinding * binding = [[[ClientServiceSOAPBinding alloc] initWithSOAPAddress:kSOAPServiceEndPoint] autorelease]; 
typens_ClientServiceRequest *request = [[ClientServiceRequestRequest new] autorelease];
ClientServiceSOAPBindingResponse *responseObj = [binding ClientOperationUsingPayload:request];
```

the responseObj should now hold the response from your webservice. Hope that helps,

Cheers.

**EDIT:**

We later found out that if a property name has a "dot" in it's name (e.g.  <`xs:element name="Foo.Bar"`) the wsdl2objc generator does not subsitute the dot and generated ivars contain the very same dot - the code is full of syntax errors and does not compile.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I can't seem to make it work in the first place! I configured the two steps in the project configuration and now i get this with compiling: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token

Comment: I edited my first post in what piece of code gives this error!

Comment: can you mark the line where the error ocurred?

edit:
are the "spaces" between RetrieveAsyncUsing and 'delegate' in your source, or is this a copy-paste mistake? If the former, try deleting them.

Comment: Hmm, there are spaces... I changed it to a :, this seems to help. Is it possible if I give you a link to my original generated files, to help me the good direction? If so, www.karper-forum.com/Metadata.zip! Thank you so far :)

Comment: sure. You should start off with `BasicHttpBinding_entities *binding = [[BasicHttpBinding_entities alloc] initWithAddress:@"http://yourserver:1234/foo"]; ` then try calling your ws with `BasicHttpBinding_entitiesResponse *response = [req RetrieveUsing]; `  This should do it synchronously, if it works perhaps try `- (void)RetrieveAsyncUsing delegate:(id<BasicHttpBinding_entitiesResponseDelegate>)responseDelegate;` to have non blocking async method.

Comment: It seems I finally have some communication, but the operation doesn't seem to be implemented in my outgoing XML. I make a binding: BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBinding *binding = [[MetadataSvc BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBinding] initWithAddress:@"my server"];
    BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBinding_DefinedEntities *request = [[BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBinding_DefinedEntities new] autorelease];
    BasicHttpBinding_entitiesBindingResponse *response = [binding DefinedEntitiesUsing];
My XML doesn't contain anything about the DefinedEntities operation!

Comment: will you try turning the logging on? (`binding.logXMLInOut = YES`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3618/discussion-between-mja-and-wesso)

Comment: I wanted to say, i think I found a better program to turn WSDL into Objective-C, at www.sudzc.com it got generated perfectly!